# oracle select filter by file content

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm facing an issue, due to a miss of knowleadge I guess..

how can I do the folowing query on an ORACLE database:

```
Select toto from my_table where value in (my_value.txt);
```

my_value.txtis a text file like:

```
'1111','2222','123123','12323',... etc...
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: Go read this - http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to create an EXTERNAL TABLE for this. You can create a table based on underlying file contents and then query this table. I suggest you have a read of this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

If you do a search for 'loading csv files using an external table', you should find quite a few resources online.